# jqplot how to highlight a point

Tags: jqplot

I have a set of already drawn jqplot plots, and I want to respond to mouse movement in any one of these plots simultaneously in all those plots. Thus, when the user moves over a data point in a plot, all  plots in this set that contain that data point should also highlight that point in their respective plots. And when the mouse is moved away, also unhighlight together.

Is there an already existing way to do such collective mouse highlighting?

Alternatively, is there a way to drive point marking in a plot via user coordinates? Then I could imagine a plot-collection, and respond to mousemove event to maintain state of each member plot and drive highlighting/unhighlighting.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So I created a mousing manager class and had the highlighter drive a suitably initialized mousing manager instance object instead of doing what it used to do on event. The mousing manager in turn goes through all registered jqplot objects in the document, finds functionally equivalent neighbor points in them, and drives their respective highlighters with  correct neighbor information to do what it used to do on mouse events.

Yes, it's a hack, but does the job for now :) I wish I could have this as a plugin but then it will have to own a highlighter; and I don't know enough javascript or jquery to do that sort of trick. So now I have a few tweaked plugins and a lot of worries about maintainability. Will surely appreciate a good reference to this art of javascripting.